# Python Socket Not Able To Connect To Windows Server

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, python, socket, windows-server-2019

I am using socket library in python and want to connect client (my computer) to server (AWS EC2 Windows instance).
But client always give error:- **"TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"**

Solutions that I had already implemented:-

1. Edit security group to enable required incoming ports.
2. Allocate static IP for EC2 instance
3. Restart EC2
4. Enable incoming port from windows firewall inside EC2 instance

When I go to task manager >> performance >> Resourece Monitor, I can see that port is open:-

- NetWork Activity

Image   PID Address Send (B/sec)    Receive (B/sec) Total (B/sec)

pythonw.exe 1456    EC2AMAZ-XXXXXX  627 647 1,274

- TCP Connections

Image       PID   Local Address  Local Port Remote Address  Remote Port Packet Loss (%) Latency (ms)

pythonw.exe 1456    IPv4 loopback   50770   IPv4 loopback   50769   0   0

- Listening Ports

Image   PID Address Port    Protocol    Firewall Status

pythonw.exe 1456    IPv4 loopback   3469    TCP Allowed, not restricted

But I am still not able to ping EC2 on required port (telnet PUBLIC_IP PORT). And hence client is not able to connect via socket.

---

server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 3469

s.bind(('localhost', port))
print ('Socket binded to port 3469')

s.listen(1)
print ('socket is listening')





while True:

    try:

        print('waiting for connection')
        connection, client_address = s.accept()
        print ('Got connection from ', client_address)

        data = connection.recv(16)
        print('received {!r}'.format(data))

        connection.close(); s.close();break;

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        connection.close(); s.close();break;
```

Client.py

```
import socket 


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


port = 3469


s.connect(('EC2-PUBLIC-IP-ADDRESS-OF-EC2-HERE', port))

z = 'Hello World'


s.sendall(z.encode())

s.close()
```

---

This code works perfectly fine when both server and client are on  localhost.

Can't figure out what is missing. Please help.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

> s.bind(('localhost', port))

You appear to only be listening on `localhost` which is the loopback address and not available on the public internet.

Comment: Thanks @user570574 . Solved it by replacing localhost with IP address (cmd>>ipconfig).